# fatal error: sys/times.h: no such file or directory When I'm trying to compile C code it gives me an error

Tags: c, cygwin, mingw

I'm trying to compile c code which I uploaded from github. I have installed mingw, also tried to install cygwin compiler
but I have such kind of error fatal error: sys/times.h: no such file or directory